# Quotes and special character issue in set and append variable in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to prepare a variable value using set and append variable that needs to be passed to the request body of the copy activity to fetch the data from API. I need to do lookup of 100 values from DB at a time and form a array of values but " (quote) value is getting appended in the starting, end and in between of values due to which the copy activity is failing. I'm trying for the first two values as of now. `"[\"{\\\"RIC\\\":{\\\"Value\\\":\\\"FHN.N\\\"}}\",\"{\\\"RIC\\\":{\\\"Value\\\":\\\"0142.HK\\\"}}\"]"` this is the final variable output that I'm getting, I've removed the additional \ (slashes) using @replace(string(variables('RIC')),'','') and the output was - `"[\"{\"RIC\":{\"Value\":\"FHN.N\"}}\",\"{\"RIC\":{\"Value\":\"0142.HK\"}}\"]"` due to the " quotes in between the two RIC values and in between }] in the starting and at the end it's failing. If I can get the output as "[{"RIC":{"Value":"FHN.N"}},{"RIC":{"Value":"0142.HK"}}]" it would solve the issue as I tried passing this manually.

Request body passed in copy activity - "{"GetSignificantDevelopments_Request_1":{"FindRequest":{"CompanyIdentifiers_typehint":["CompanyIdentifiers","CompanyIdentifiers"],"CompanyIdentifiers":["{"RIC":{"Value":"FHN.N"}}","{"RIC":{"Value":"0142.HK"}}"],"StartDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00","EndDate": "2021-01-06T00:00:00","Significance": "1 2 3","MaxNumberOfItems": 100}}}", - this is failing

manually tried successful request body - "{"GetSignificantDevelopments_Request_1":{"FindRequest":{"CompanyIdentifiers_typehint":["CompanyIdentifiers","CompanyIdentifiers"],"CompanyIdentifiers":[{"RIC":{"Value":"FHN.N"}},{"RIC":{"Value":"0142.HK"}}],"StartDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00","EndDate": "2021-01-06T00:00:00","Significance": "1 2 3","MaxNumberOfItems": 100}}}",

Answer (score 1):

The other way would be to use Replace function to replace all unwanted characters from the variable like :
@replace(string(variables('RIC')),'','')
where `\` is just one of the characters. You can keep on concatenating replace functions to replace other characters  and achieve your output.
Hope this would be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks @Nandan, I used replace function and got desired output. @replace(replace(replace(replace(string(variables('RIC')),'\',''),'["{','[{'),'}"]','}]'),'}","{','},{')

Comment: Great to know ☺️ @kunal sinha
Could you please mark it as answer so it would be beneficial for the community if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to transform `"[\"{\"RIC\":{\"Value\":\"FHN.N\"}}\",\"{\"RIC\":{\"Value\":\"0142.HK\"}}\"]"`. Because it's not a valid JSON Data. You can try to use `substring` function to get two JSON object `{"RIC":{"Value":"FHN.N"}}` and `{"RIC":{"Value":"0142.HK"}}`. And then use `concat` function to compose your request body like this:

```
@{concat('{"GetSignificantDevelopments_Request_1":{"FindRequest":{"CompanyIdentifiers_typehint":["CompanyIdentifiers","CompanyIdentifiers"],"CompanyIdentifiers":[',json(substring(variables('RIC'),2,24)),',',json(substring(variables('RIC'),30,26)),'],"StartDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00","EndDate": "2021-01-06T00:00:00","Significance": "1 2 3","MaxNumberOfItems": 100}}}')}
```

Comment: thanks Steve, but the RIC length will vary for different RIC values. so i'm using replace function.

Answer (score 0):

I used the replace function and got the desired output.

```
@replace(replace(replace(replace(string(variables('RIC')),'\',''),'["{','[{'),'}"]','}]'),'}","{','},{')
```